# Nuget [exec] WARNING: Unable to extract metadata from *.dll

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, nuget

While generating nugget package getting below warning.

```
 [exec] WARNING: Unable to extract metadata from *.dll
```

We started facing this issue after changing the target plarform to x64.

Does anybody know the fix for this issue?

Comment: I had generated the assembly using x64 platform. Nuget is able to extract assembly metadata if I build using AnyCPU Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with latest version of Nuget, it does not extract the metadata from the assembly built using 64 bit. If you generate the assembly using AnyCPU platform then only Nuget will extract the metadata.

I was able to fix this issue with workaround as mentioned below:

- Preferably use AnyCPU platform unless you have specific requirements.
- If you are using build platform other than AnyCPU then replace assembly metadata symbols with actual value.